# How to call a method after hitting Enter in a Razor Component?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a razor component with the following text field

```
<input @bind=nameToAdd @onsubmit="AddName" />
```

I want to call the `AddName` method after user hits the enter button from the textbox. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is put the input in its own `EditForm` and handle `OnValidSubmit` done it many times works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for a similar purpose in many projects. On enter it resets the focus to the input. It uses the templates bootstrap 5.

Usage:

```
<SendBox OnSend=SomeMethod />

@code {
    void SomeMethod(string input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`SendBox.razor`

```
<EditForm Model="@SendBoxViewModel" OnValidSubmit="@Send">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="@DivClass">
        <input @ref="@inputBox"
               @bind-value="SendBoxViewModel.InputMessage"
               @bind-value:event="oninput"
               type="text"
               aria-label="@Placeholder"
               placeholder="@Placeholder"
               class="@InputClass"
               aria-describedby="button-send"
               disabled=@Disabled>

        <button class="@ButtonClass"
                type="submit"
                id="button-send"
                disabled=@Disabled>
            @Label
        </button>

    </div>
    <ValidationMessage For=@(() => SendBoxViewModel.InputMessage) />

</EditForm>
```

**Note:** `OnSubmit` can be used here. The use of the `DataAnnotationsValidator` and `ValidationMessage` is not required for the functionality your after. The button can be hidden if required however some people use touch screens ;).

I use the code behind approach:

`SendBox.razor.cs`

```
public partial class SendBox : ComponentBase
{
    private ElementReference inputBox;

    [Parameter]
    public string Label { get; set; } = "Send";

    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; } = "Type a new message here.";

    [Parameter]
    public string DivClass { get; set; } = "input-group";

    [Parameter]
    public string InputClass { get; set; } = "form-control";

    [Parameter]
    public string ButtonClass { get; set; } = "btn btn-outline-primary";

    [Parameter]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnSend { get; set; }

    public SendBoxViewModel SendBoxViewModel { get; set; } = new SendBoxViewModel();

    private bool MessageInputInvalid => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SendBoxViewModel.InputMessage);

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (!MessageInputInvalid)
        {
            await OnSend.InvokeAsync(SendBoxViewModel.InputMessage);
            SendBoxViewModel.InputMessage = string.Empty;
            await inputBox.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class SendBoxViewModel
{
    [MinLength(length: 1)]
    [MaxLength(length: 1024)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Empty messages are not allowed!")]
    public string InputMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the `onkeypress` event handler. This event handler fires for every keypress, so you'll need to look for the enter key specifically, which is Key = 13, or Code = Enter.  You can search 'KeyboardEventArgs' for the list of keys and codes.

`Component.razor`

```cs
<h3>Component</h3>

<input @bind=nameToAdd @onkeypress="HandleKeyPress" @onsubmit="AddName" />

@code {
    public string nameToAdd { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public void AddName()
    {
        //Add Name logic here
        //..
        //Clear the input box when done
        nameToAdd = string.Empty;
    }

    private void HandleKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs keyboardEventArgs)
    {
        if (keyboardEventArgs.Code == "Enter")
        {
            AddName();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got `onsubmit`, but here's the *basic* concept using `onchange` and `oninput`.

```cs
@page "/"

<div class="m-2 p-3">
    <h3>On enter/loose focus</h3>
    <input value=@nameToAdd @onchange="AddName" />
    <div>
        value: @nameToAdd
    </div>
</div>
<div class="m-2 p-3">
    <h3>On keystroke</h3>
    <input value=@nameToAdd2 @oninput="AddName2" />
    <div>
        value2: @nameToAdd2
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string? nameToAdd;
    private string? nameToAdd2;

    private void AddName(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        nameToAdd = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }

    private void AddName2(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        nameToAdd2 = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Copy and paste into *index.razor* in a new solution.

`@onsubmit` does nothing on an `input`.  `@bind` sets `value` to the specified property and `@onchange` to an anonymous method that updates the specified property.